# Django, creating cache key from request object

Tags: django

I have been assigned a new project. In this django project the previous developer uses `django.core.cache` module a lot.

I decided to keep it like this.

My question is this. Can I make a unique string out of the request object that would let me know if the request object is the same as before?

Request comes with a set of 15 parameters (even more) and it is hard to choose one or some of them to create a key. It has to be all, because different combinations lead to different results.

This is the code I want to change (some code left out for brevity):

```
@login_required
def compare(request, username):
    cache_key = 'key__%d' % (request.GET.to_unique_id_or_similar())
    cache_value = cache.get(cache_key)
    if cache_value is not None:
        return cache_value
```

Comment: You could create a string from the parameters, generate then a MD5 for the name and compare it / use it as the cache key.

Comment: Thanks, I have thought of that, too. But how can I be sure that `request.GET` dictionary object will return the values always in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django provides a super easy way to do this with the [@cache_page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache) decorator.